# Running OpenFlow on a switch

Tags: network-programming, openflow

I want to run OpenFlow on a switch.

I have root privileges on a switch that does not support OpenFlow yet.

How can I make this switch support OpenFlow and then control traffic flow on it from outside the box?

Basically I want to start experimenting with OpenFlow. Where do I start from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way for users to enable OpenFlow on switches that do not support the functionality.

The easiest way to start experimenting with OpenFlow is to download the [Floodlight](http://www.projectfloodlight.org/floodlight/) controller VM image. Floodlight is an open source OpenFlow controller written in Java. The virtual machine available on the download page is an Ubuntu based image. When you start up the image the Floodlight controller will already be running. The image also includes [Mininet](http://mininet.org/) in it. Mininet allows the creation of virtual networks inside a single instance of Linux. this will allow you to create any arbitrary network topology of OpenFlow-enabled software switches and connect it to the Floodlight controller.

Answer (score 2):

**Tools, Tutorials and Online course** to get started working in Software Defined Networking Field:

> Network Emulators and Simulators

1) Mininet (Emulator; Learning curve: Easy; Open source)

2) Estinet (Simulator & Emulator; Learning curve: Moderate; Proprietary)

3) ns-3 (Simulator; Learning curve: Difficult; Open source)

> South bound API'S

1) [NOX](http://www.noxrepo.org/) (Programming language: C; Learning curve: Moderate; Open flow 1.0; Open source)

2) [POX](http://www.noxrepo.org/pox/about-pox/) (Programming Language: Python; Learning Curve: Easy - Moderate; Open flow 1.0; Open source)

3) [Flood light](http://www.projectfloodlight.org/floodlight/) (Programming Language: Java; Learning curve: Difficult; Open flow 1.0; Kind of Open source)

4) [Ryu](http://osrg.github.io/ryu/) (Programming Language: Python; Learning curve: Moderate; Open flow 1.0/1.1/1.3;Open source)

> North bound API's

1) [Pyretic](http://frenetic-lang.org/pyretic/)

2) [Frenetic](http://frenetic-lang.org/overview.php)

3) [Route Flow](https://sites.google.com/site/routeflow/)

> Tutorials

1) [Open flow](http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/OpenFlow_Tutorial)

2) [Mininet walk through](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/)

3) [POX Tutorial](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki)

> Online Courses

1) [Software Defined Networking](https://www.coursera.org/course/sdn) (Awesome course)

2) Many company does consulting workshops in this field as well

> [Misc Relevant Projects](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/of-sw.html)

Answer (score 1):

For some hardware switches, there may also be firmware upgrades available that enable OpenFlow. You may want to check in with your switch vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Also I want to add

!. [OpenDayLight Controller](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/opendaylight/#!)

Join the mailing list:
[Mininet-Discussion](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/)